# Casting User-Provided Numbers to Integers and Floats in Python

Tags: python, user-input

I'm trying to create a change return program that takes in a cost of an item and the money given and returns the proper change in terms of notes, quarters, dimes, etc.

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm stuck on trying to split it up. I've looked on StackOverflow and found the method `math.modf(x)` to be relevant. However, I am having a hard time implementing it.

Can you please let me know why `change` and `y` `is not defined`?

Thanks

```
import math

def changereturn():

    quarter = 0.25
    dime = 0.1
    nickel = 0.05
    penny = 0.01

    cost = float(raw_input('Please enter the cost of the item in USD: '))
    money = float(raw_input('Please enter the amount of money given in USD: '))

    change = money - cost


    y = math.modf(change) 

    return change
    return y
```

Answer (score 1):

A function (`def`) can only `return` one time, but python allows you to return tuples for result.

This implementation may be what you need:

```
import math

def changereturn():
    quarter = 0.25
    dime = 0.1
    nickel = 0.05
    penny = 0.01

    cost = float(input('Please enter the cost of the item in USD: '))
    money = float(input('Please enter the amount of money given in USD: '))

    change = money - cost

    y = math.modf(change) 

    return change, y

print(changereturn())
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I assign the integer part to a variable and the float part to another variable? thanks

Comment: replace his `print(changereturn())` with my `change, y = changereturn()`

Answer (score 1):

First issue is you never run your changereturn() function.  Second issue is the two `return` lines in the changereturn() function.  The second function which sends the y will never be run.  You can return (change, y) and run your program as:

```
change, y = changereturn()

print change
print y
```

You need to put this at the very bottom without indenting.  Personally, I don't like returning multiple things from a function.  Normally I'd suggest catching it as a tuple and then printing each portion.  Your question feels a bit like an assignment for a Comp Sci first year student so I don't want to 1)solve it for you and 2) make it overly complex.